# executing query via middleware

Tags: middleware, loopbackjs, strongloop

While using strongloop loopback I want check the database for accesstoken and username existence in every request.

So i am making a middleware code:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return function xAuth(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
  };
};
```

I have added it to :initial" middleware json

```
  "initial": {
    "compression": {},
    "cors": {
      "params": {
        "origin": true,
        "credentials": true,
        "maxAge": 86400
      }
    },
    "./middleware/trumptAuth": {},
    "helmet#xssFilter": {},
    "helmet#frameguard": {
      "params": [
        "deny"
      ]
    },
    "helmet#hsts": {
      "params": {
        "maxAge": 0,
        "includeSubdomains": true
      }
    },
    "helmet#hidePoweredBy": {},
    "helmet#ieNoOpen": {},
    "helmet#noSniff": {},
    "helmet#noCache": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  }
```

i want to execute an sql query here but i have no idea on how can i do that, I probably just need "app" variable access or directly "dataSource" access.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access "app" variable from middleware use

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var app = req.app;
  ...
});
```

To access "dataSource" variable from middleware use

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var dataSource = app.datasources.db;
  ...
});
```

To access an specific model from middleware use

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var app = req.app;
  var modelName = app.model.modelName;
  ...
});
```

for more methods/sources use this documentation link
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Working+with+LoopBack+objects

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, "Using variables in middleware" (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Defining+middleware#Definingmiddleware-Usingvariablesinvalues), it looks like you can pass any part of the app object using this syntax: `${var}`. The datasource property exists under the core app object, so you should be able to pass it in that way.

Comment: Thank You, I actually solved but could not post the answer. The answer is actually simple and i'll justy post it right now. we just need to do var xyzModel = req.app.xyzModel;

Comment: Ah nice. So I guess the feature I linked to above could be considered an alternative. :)

Comment: probably yes but i don't see the actual use unless you want something very specific that will not be there in 'app'

Comment: Well it works with app though - as the docs say. Maybe it is a more 'formal' way of sending it along. Meh - whatevers - glad you got it. :)

Comment: On second thoughts no. the doc you specify is actually using variables to load properties (application-wide or express specific) but not objects or models. you will not get 'app' variable but "environment" or a "loopback config file" which won't be present in the actual "app" variable

Comment: You sure? My read of it was 'so and so property of app', which would include datasources.

Comment: it is only for configuring the middleware, dynamic middlewares based on (for eg:) environment or dynamic path (for eg:) restApiRoot.. it does not  expose variables to be used inside the middleware it configures the middleware itself

Comment: Ah I think I see the difference now. Thanks for helping me learn!